# excel 2007 vba: how to refer to HPageBreaks

Tags: excel, page-break, vba

I'm trying to write a macro which can look into the list of horizontal page breaks that a worksheet keeps, and it seems like HPageBreaks should be exactly that.  I can add or remove page breaks from it, but I can't seem to isolate the collection itself to look at its contents.  Even adding a watch and looking at ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks just brings up a generic looking object with a count field equal to 0 regardless of existing page breaks.

I'm really confused about this now.  Is there any way to look into the existing page breaks within a sheet?  A listing of what rows they occur on/between would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
Sub testing()
    MsgBox "There are " & ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count & " pagebreaks."
    For Each pb In ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks
        MsgBox "a page break lies between rows " & pb.Location.Row - 1 _
            & " and " & pb.Location.Row
    Next
End Sub
```

Here are some (rather scanty) references.:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa661442(office.10).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa206426(office.10).aspx

Comment: hmm, so I guess all interaction with it is indirect... VBA has some weird little quirks to it

Comment: ugh... and it also doesn't seem to recognize a pagebreak if there's no content yet underneath it.  Thanks for the help, man!

Comment: Yeah...not a fan of VBA myself.  It is way too kludgy with very little documentation.

Comment: It's great for older users who need something familiar to get them to buy into using something new.